# build and display an html page in a table cell aspx c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to create some reports for my project. My solution for desktop applications was to use a form with a "web browser" component, build the report in html, and use the html string as the display text. This works very well and allows me to create custom reports without any reporting tools (I'm using the express versions of VS. No reporting tools included). However, I have no idea how to do this in an aspx page. I can build the report, just need to know how to get it in the target cell and how to make sure the report is displayed properly and not as the raw string that holds it.

code below:

```
<table style="width: 100%; height: 690px;">
   <tr>
      <td class="auto-style2">Select Report Type</td>
      <td class="auto-style3">
         <asp:Button ID="btnTodayReport" runat="server" OnClick="btnTodayReport_Click" Text="Today's Orders" />
      </td>
      <td class="auto-style4">
         <asp:Button ID="btWeeklyReport" runat="server" Text="Weekly Report" OnClick="btnRunReport_Click" />
      </td>
      <td class="auto-style5">
         &nbsp;
      </td>
      <td class="auto-style1">
         &nbsp;&nbsp;
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td colspan="5" style="border-style: solid">**This is where the report should display**</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

As requested, below is the code to build the html string. It's from old code but I'll be using the same approach for this project, or at least would like to use this. wb is the WebBrowser component for a WinForms application.

```
private void btnGetReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // get the data for the report
        wb.DocumentText = RepBuild.BuildAverageReport(dtStart.Value, dtEnd.Value);

    }    

public static string BuildReview(review rev)
    {
        int questID = 0;
        string Body = "";

        Body = "<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV=\"Content-Type\" CONTENT=\"text/html;charset=windows-1252\">" +
            "<TITLE>Ticket Review for " + rev.RevEmpName + "</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>";

        Body += "<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0 ><TR HEIGHT=40 >" +
            "<TD ALIGN=LEFT BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF ><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:18pt FACE=\"Segoe UI\" COLOR=#204d89>Ticket Review for " + rev.RevEmpName + "</FONT></TD>" +
            "</TR></TABLE><TABLE HEIGHT=150></TABLE>";

        // show the questions in order
        Body += "<table border='1' width = '800px' align = 'center'> <tr>" +
            "<td rowspan = '3' width = '80px'><b>Number </b></td><td rowspan = '3' width = '80px'><b>Score </b></td>" +
            "<td width = '600px'><b>Question </b></td></tr><tr><td><b>Comments</b></td></tr> </Table>";

        while (questID <= rev.RevQuestions.Count - 1)
        {
            if ((questID % 2) == 0)//the number is even
            {
                Body += "<table border='1' width = '800px' align = 'center'><tr>" +
                "<td rowspan = '3' width = '80px'>" + rev.RevQuestions[questID].QuestID.ToString() + " </td> <td rowspan = '3' width = '80px'> " +
                rev.RevQuestions[questID].QuestScore + " </td> " +
                " <td width = '600px'> " + rev.RevQuestions[questID].QuestText + " </td> </tr> <tr> <td><b> " +
                rev.RevQuestions[questID].QuestComment + " </b></td> </tr> </table> ";

            }
            else
            {
                Body += "<table border='1' width = '800px' align = 'center' bgcolor='#cccccc'><tr>" +
                "<td rowspan = '3' width = '80px'>" + rev.RevQuestions[questID].QuestID.ToString() + " </td> <td rowspan = '3' width = '80px'> " +
                rev.RevQuestions[questID].QuestScore + " </td> " +
                " <td width = '600px'> " + rev.RevQuestions[questID].QuestText + " </td> </tr> <tr> <td><b> " +
                rev.RevQuestions[questID].QuestComment + " </b></td> </tr> </table> ";
            }

            questID++;
        }

        Body += "<BR><BR>";

        Body += "<Table width = '400px' align = 'left'>";

        Body += "<TR>";
        Body += "<TD><b>Reviewed By</b></TD>";
        Body += "<TD> " + rev.RevLeadName + "</TD>";
        Body += "</TR>";

        Body += "<TR>";
        Body += "<TD><b>Review Date</b></TD>";
        Body += "<TD> " + rev.RevDate.ToShortDateString() + "</TD>";
        Body += "</TR>";

        Body += "<TR>";
        Body += "<TD><b>Overall Score</b></TD>";
        Body += "<TD> " + rev.RevScore + " out of 100</TD>";
        Body += "</TR>";

        Body += "<TR>";
        Body += "<TD><b>Ticket Date</b></TD>";
        Body += "<TD> " + rev.RevTickDate + "</TD>";
        Body += "</TR>";

        Body += "<TR>";
        Body += "<TD><b>Ticket Number</b></TD>";
        Body += "<TD> " + rev.RevTickNum + "</TD>";
        Body += "</TR>";

        Body += "</TABLE>";

        Body += "</HTML>";

        return Body;

    }
```

Comment: You should also include the C# code.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this issue. First I had to change the  tag so that I could reference it in the code behind. I set it to run at the server and gave it an ID.

```
<td id="ReportCell" runat="server" colspan="5" style="border-style: solid">
```

After that I could use the ReportCell.InnerHtml member to set the html string of the cell. Then I just needed to build the html from the report data and display it. It's probably not the best way to do this, and the html is not tab formatted. I looked into using the HtmlTextWriter but I wanted to keep it simple and it looked like I would have to add a bunch of code to accomplish the same thing.

I'm adding this in case anyone else has a similar situation and needs the answer.

Code below:

```
// added runat="server" and id="ReportCell"
<tr style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top">
            <td id="ReportCell" runat="server" colspan="5" style="border-style: solid">

                <br />

                <br />

            </td>
        </tr>
```

code behind:
I create a new string and start loading it with the html for the report. Start a table and fill in the first cells as the header.

```
protected void btnTodayReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // show the orders that were completed today
        string Body = "";
        DateTime yesterday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

        Body = "<font size=\"6\">Orders Completed Yesterday: " + yesterday.ToShortDateString() + "</font><br />";
        Body += "<br />";

        Body += "<table style=\"width: 100%; height: 100%;\" >";

        // Table colomn header
        Body += "<tr>";
        Body += "<td><b>Order#</b></td>";
        Body += "<td><b>Site ID</b></td>";
        Body += "<td><b>Location</b></td>";
        Body += "<td><b>VAR</b></td>";
        Body += "<td><b>Server</b></td>";
        Body += "<td><b>Install Tech</b></td>";
        Body += "<td><b>QA Tech</b></td>";
        Body += "<td><b>Notes</b></td>";
        Body += "</tr>";

        // fill the table with data 
        int count = 0;
        Body += Data.ReportYesterdysOrders(yesterday,ref count);            

        Body += "</tabl>";
        Body += "Number of Orders Completed: " + count.ToString() + "<br />";
        Body += "<br />";
        ReportCell.InnerHtml = Body;
    }
```

From the static Data class:

I connect to the database and pull back the data for the report. As the DataReader loops through the returned rows, I add each as a row in the html table and return the string. This way all the data is added in the string in the correct place.

```
public static string ReportYesterdysOrders(DateTime yesterday, ref int count)
    {
        try
        {
            string result = "";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constr);
            conn.Open();
            string qry = "Select OrderNumber, SiteID, Location, Customer, Server, InstallTech, QATech, Notes from SalesOrders" +
                " where DateCompleted = @yesterday";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(qry, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yesterday", yesterday.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

            MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                result += "<tr>";
                result += "<td>" + dr["OrderNumber"].ToString() + "</td>";
                result += "<td>" + dr["SiteID"].ToString() + "</td>";
                result += "<td>" + dr["Location"].ToString() + "</td>";
                result += "<td>" + dr["Customer"].ToString() + "</td>";
                result += "<td>" + dr["Server"].ToString() + "</td>";
                result += "<td>" + dr["InstallTech"].ToString() + "</td>";
                result += "<td>" + dr["QATech"].ToString() + "</td>";
                result += "<td>" + dr["Notes"].ToString() + "</td>";
                result += "</tr>";
                count++;
            }
            conn.Close();
            return result;
        }
        catch (MySqlException e)
        {
            return e.Message;
        }
    }
```

The output is a formatted html report that can be selected, copied, or printed from the targeted cell in the html table.